# Sencha touch 2 - How to make the src of the Ext.Img dynamic

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to make the src of the **Ext.Img dynamic** .

```
Ext.define('App.view.Welcomescreen', {

    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    xtype: 'welcomescreen',

    config: {      
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: 'http://src.sencha.io/screen.width/http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: 'http://src.sencha.io/screen.width/http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: 'http://src.sencha.io/screen.width/http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png',
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I want to give the value to the "src" using store.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to use [Ext.dataview.DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView) with

```
config: {
 itemTpl = "<img src={source}>",
 inline: true
}
```

If bound to a store, it will refresh itself on demand, unfortunately you will lose the carousel effects without some additional modification.

Comment: Thanks David , But I want to use the carousel .

Comment: If you're stuck on the carousel, you will need to bind a store to the view, add a listener for the store's refresh event to your view, and use some sort of template mechanism to take each record in the store to generate the Ext.Img's src.   From that point, subsequent refreshes can either be handled by rebuilding all child items or doing a diff of updated data to existing elements.